# What are the software tools required in each step of the web development from getting the design to submitting to the client?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, web-deployment

What is the web development(PHP - MySQL) process after designers deliver the design/look of a web site to the developers , to submiting the finished project to the project manager?
 Developing lets say being done by more than one guy, and it involves testing , debugging , database design etc.
 what are the steps a company follows or if i want to be a freelancer and what are the tools and knowledge required to do it efficiently?( free onces).
 I know HTML, CSS, Javascript(JQuery), php, frameworks (Laravel 4, CI). I hope i get answers from the experienced web developers which are going to help me join a company as a web developer or if i want to be a freelance web developer in future.

Comment: Dependency management tools like Composer; PHPUnit for TDD and unit testing generally; Static Analysis tools like phpmd and pdepend; deployment tools like Capistrano

Comment: Here we are answering code questions and issues ... This question is extremely broad and you are basically asking us to give you a hands-on solution and save you the whole thought process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is likely to be closed as the answer will change over time, so is not a good fit here. The "generic" answer is...

#### Source Control

If working as part of a team, source control is an absolute must (be it Mercurial, Subversion, Team Foundation Server or something else entirely).

This allows you to share work between team members and also covers the "What if Bob gets hit by a bus" scenario. At least Bob will know his code won't be lost, so it's not all bad...

#### An IDE

I consider an IDE to be crucial to productivity (Visual Studio/Eclipse/etc). I do know some devs who insist a text editor is all you need but I personally find I can get things done faster with an IDE.

#### A Build/Test system

You probably won't need to set this up yourself (at least not at first) but you'll need to write unit tests for your code. Quite often tis system is tied into source control (so a checkin will cause all unit tests to be run to make sure you haven't broken anything).

Of course, how exactly tests are defined will depend on the language/framework/project.

#### Maintainable code

Not really a tool but something I've found a lot of solo developers don't consider... When working with others, making sure your code can be understood by someone else can be *more* important than having it work efficiently. That means things like useful variable names (I once saw code that started `$Zeus = $_INPUT[...]`), making sure your code is [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), not thinking of complex SQL queries as one long string, etc, etc. I could go on forever.